# Chrome Extension using popup bar

Tags: javascript, popup, google-chrome

I'm trying to make something similar to the picture below.

http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/8844/testi.jpg

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work within the extension. I get an error stating there was "Error loading the document". The screenshot above was done using a locally made html with the iBox javascript. Is there any other javascript library that would permit me to load my popup html the same way it does with an icon in the bar?

This is how the code was implemented locally to open the popup:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 81 && e.altKey && !e.shiftKey && e.ctrlKey) {
            iBox.showURL('search.html');
            }
        }, false);
```

This is the function in iBox library:

```
showURL: function(url, title, params) {
        showInit(title, params, function() {
            for (var i=0; i<_pub.plugins.list.length; i++) {
                var plugin = _pub.plugins.list[i];
                if (plugin.match(url)) {
                    active.plugin = plugin;
                    plugin.render(url, active.params);
                    break;
                }}});}
```

This is the xmlhttp request:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
            http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (http.overrideMimeType) {
                // set type accordingly to anticipated content type
                http.overrideMimeType('text/html');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Post a code snippet: I might be able to help.

Comment: Updated, tell me if that's what you we're looking for

Comment: and where is the "search.html" document located?

Comment: Inside the same folder. Same thing for the extension which opens the little popup window when I click on the icon in the bar

Comment: maybe `ibox.showURL` is modifying the URL passed... could you check?

Comment: I think it just simply doesn't know where to looko for this extension. I tried using iBox.showURL(chrome.extension.getURL('search.html')) but I don't the URL given back is the right one

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the permissions in `manifest.json` aren't properly set. If the extension relies on making XMLHttpRequest, you need to look at this [doc](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html).

Of course, if all the dependent files for the `iBox` "application" are all located in your extension folder, it should be OK.

Comment: Yes it is. I'm also loading it at start in the manifest.json with "js": [ "contentScript.js", "ibox.js" ]

Comment: What do you mean? is the `permissions` list set accordingly? please clarify.

Comment: Sorry about that. What I meant is that the "content_scripts" had the above line. The permissions simply has the "tabs" and "bookmarks" for the extensions functionally

Comment: check with the "developer tools" if iBox makes XMLHttpRequests to an external origin.

Comment: I think you we're right. I'll take a look at the doc you suggested. I put the code of what I found in my question

Comment: Is my answer/help satisfactory then?